# Reset password in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4, reset-password

I'm stuck in implementing reset password in Symfony 4. Here the user inserts an e-mail on forgot-password form, then he receives an  email with a link which directs to reset-password form. I have the following method in my forgot-password controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/forgot-password", name="forgot_password", defaults={"email=null"})
 * @Method({"GET","POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
 * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
 * @param $email
 * @return Response
 */
public function forgotpass(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ForgotPassType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $email = $form->getData();
        $users = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Users::class)
            ->findOneBy(array('email' => $email['email']));

            $identifier = random_bytes(10);

                $url = $this->generateUrl('reset_password', array('email'=>$email['email'], 'identifier'=>$identifier));

                return $this->redirectToRoute('url');
}
```

I am trying to generate the URL which will be sent via email to reset the password. The URL contains email and an identifier with reset-password link. But it is showing following errors

```
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "http://myweb.test/reset-password?email=email%40gmail.com&identifier=%EEJ8f%A2%DEN%F0%01A" as such route does not exist.
```

Can anyone tell me please what went wrong here ? Is my approach to generate the URL ok?

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you didn't post the entire method including the routing part but i assume that in your annotation you forgot to do something like this /password/reset/{token} similar to

```
@Route("/{id}/edit", name="portofolio_album_edit", methods="GET|POST")
```

Comment: the method for this one ?                 $url = $this->generateUrl('reset_password', array('email'=>$email['email'], 'identifier'=>$identifier));

Comment: but now that i see your controller method the route named reset_password doesn't exist so you will have to create a new route that will accept your parameters and from there on you will have to do the logic part.